# получить нужную локаль для системы

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows

Например у меня в линуксе стоит есть локаль ru_RU.UTF-8. Для игры, чтобы правильно работал русский шрифт при вводе текста, мне нужно писать такую команду.

```
setlocale ( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8" );
```

Но дело в том, что если мою программу или игру вдруг запустят в бразилии например, то у они не смогут ввести текст своего алфавита, если у них не английский. Вот и вопрос. Как мне узнать какая локаль для системы на первом месте? Неужели мне надо будет по файлам бегать и смотреть какие есть локали. И как это сделать в линукс и windows?

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе вы писали что `mbstowcs` не хочет без локали работать. Может тогда чтобы не возиться с локалью, самому написать преобразование UTF8 в UTF32 (вроде вам такое нужно), или использовать какую-нибудь стороннюю библиотеку? Еще, есть предположение, что подходит любая локаль с UTF8. Попробуйте что-то типа `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а точно, подходит даже en_US.UTF-8. Спасибо. Сам я не додумался проверить сначала прежде чем спрашивать.

Comment: В Windows текущую локаль системы можно получить с помощью GetUserDefaultLocaleName. Но это вам не поможет, так как в Windows `setlocale ( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8" );` НЕ дает нужного вам эффекта (корректного ввода русских символов).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать системную локаль, взятую из переменной окружения:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Получить имя текущей локали приложения, не изменяя её:

```
std::string current_locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, nullptr);
```